# Trying to come up with sql statement/java code using group by and rollup

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I need a sql statement (or I can do it in Java if that's more efficient) to display a summary table. When I only show one column with the statistics, it displays as I'd expect:

```
SELECT  refresh_job_detail.refresh_job_identifier,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Pending,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'SUCCESSFUL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Successful,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'CANCELLED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Cancelled,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'ERROR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as ERROR
from refresh_job_detail
group by rollup (refresh_job_detail.refresh_job_identifier)
```

This statement returns:

```
refresh_job_identifier  pending successful  cancelled   error
20191029162245000trphc35    0   2   0   0
20191031161442899app9919    1   1   0   0
...
(null)  11  22  0   0
```

But when I start adding columns to the `SELECT` and corresponding `GROUP BY` clauses, I get more rows with null in them, and I can't figure out why.

```
refresh_job_identifier  refresh_job_start_time  pending successful  cancelled   error
20191029162245000trphc35    2019-10-26 16:53:30 0   1   0   0
20191029162245000trphc35    2019-10-26 16:53:30 0   1   0   0
20191029162245000trphc35    (null)  0   2   0   0
20191031161442899app9919    2019-10-31 16:14:42 0   1   0   0
20191031161442899app9919    2019-10-31 16:14:42 0   1   0   0
20191031161442899app9919    (null)  0   2   0   0
...
```

I'd love for someone to explain what's happening. Is it possible to get the data to display as I'd like? Or would I be better off doing this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation functions:

```
SELECT  rjd.refresh_job_identifier, MAX(rjd.refresh_job_start_time),
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Pending,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'SUCCESSFUL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Successful,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'CANCELLED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as Cancelled,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN record_status = 'ERROR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as ERROR
from refresh_job_detail rjd
group by rollup (rjd.refresh_job_identifier);
```

Because you are using Postgres, you should simplify your query (and somewhat improve performance) using `filter`:

```
SELECT rjd.refresh_job_identifier, MAX(rjd.refresh_job_start_time),
       COUNT(*) (FILTER WHERE record_status = 'PENDING') as Pending,
       COUNT(*) (FILTER WHERE record_status = 'SUCCESSFUL') as Successful,
       COUNT(*) (FILTER WHERE record_status = 'CANCELLED') as Cancelled,
       COUNT(*) (FILTER WHERE record_status = 'ERROR') as ERROR
FROM refresh_job_detail rjd
GROUP BY ROLLUP (rjd.refresh_job_identifier);
```

Comment: Hmm, the FILTER command is giving me a syntax error... I'm using Postgres Aurora, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user1660256 . . . It was introduced in Postgres 9.4.  As far as I know, it was the first database that supports this standard syntax.

Answer (score 1):

remove ROLLUP and keep just simple GROUP BY. see docs on it from snowflake https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/group-by-rollup.html , which is also postgres.
It looks like rollup produces sub-total rows in addition to grouped rows, so that is why when you add more columns you get null values.